# Docx работа со списком

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть документ .docx в котором находится список. Как можно получить элементы этого списка?

Comment: а при чем тут wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй  [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/bb265236.aspx).